openJPA and @Converter field not persisted
I am working working on the backend to a webapp and I would like to persist a List<String> as a String using a @Converter.  Compiles Okay and when deploying I get the following WARNING message
WARNING [main] null.openjpa.Runtime Fields "com.barbeeloft.webapp.model.Employee.training" are not a default persistent type, and do not have any annotations indicating their persistence strategy. They will be treated as non-persistent. If you intended for these fields to be persistent, be sure to annotate them appropriately or declare them in orm.xml. Otherwise annotate them with @Transient.

Here is the code for the field and the Converter
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>,String> {
   
   private static final String SPLIT_CHAR = ";";
   
   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn( List<String> list ) {
      String s = list != null ? String.join( SPLIT_CHAR, list ) : "";
      System.out.println("in convertToDatabaseColumn("+ s +")" );
      return s;
   };

   @Override
   public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute( String string ) {
      List<String> l = string != null ? new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( string.split(SPLIT_CHAR)) ) : new ArrayList<String>();
      System.out.println( "in convertToEntityAttribute("+ l +")");
      return l;
   };

}
    

@Column(length=128,name="TRAINING",columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL")
@Convert(converter=StringListConverter.class,attributeName="training")
private List<String> training = new ArrayList<>();
   

I am using apache-tomee-microprofile-9.1.2 and openjpa-3.2.2-jakarta ( in tomee ) with netBeans IDE 20 and openjdk-21.0.1 ( Mac ).
Attempted to use autoApply,  different @Column attributes,  and attributeName attribute among others.

package com.barbeeloft.webapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Convert;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.barbeeloft.webapp.utils.StringListConverter;

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE") public class Employee implements Serializable {
    
@Id
@Column(length=6,name="ID")
private String id;

@Column(length=128,name="TRAINING",columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL")
@Convert(converter=StringListConverter.class,attributeName="training")
private List<String> training = new ArrayList<String>();

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<String> getTraining() {
    return training;
}

public void setTraining(List<String> training) {
    this.training = training;
}
 }



Can you please share your Employee class? Please include imports as well.

are you mixing and matching annotations on both fields and properties? Make sure you are consistent with your annotations or one set will be ignored. You might want to also specify that it is a Basic mapping type - it should figure that out from the column annotation, but doesn't hurt, and it might be getting confused when presented with a Collection type
